# Buffering a Wav file with OpenAL (java and lwjgl)

Tags: java, audio, wav, openal, lwjgl

In short, I don't want to load an entire wav file into anOpenAL buffer, and all of the tutorials to do so read in the entire .wav file at once. Are there any pages that describe a buffering scheme that I have missed?

This is to be eventually expanded to ogg mp3 and flac, but for right now wav files are a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is tutorial for streaming WAV files in C, but you can apply same concepts to Java: http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal-tutorial.html